# Unity Rigidbody player movement - how to rotate player

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I wrote a short script for player movement. Everything works as expected, but I don't know how to rotate the player in the direction of the movement.

What I want to achieve:
When I hold 'A' on the keyboard I want my player to turn to the left and walk in that direction.
What happens currently:
My player walks to the left but is still facing forward.
Same applies to all other directions.

```
    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        Move();
    }

    void Move()
    {
        Vector3 currentVelocity = rb.velocity;
        Vector3 targetVelocity = new Vector3(move.x, 0, move.y);

        if (targetVelocity != Vector3.zero && Keyboard.current.leftShiftKey.IsPressed())
        {
            isRunning = true;
        }
        else
        {
            isRunning = false;
        }

        Animator animator = GetComponent<Animator>();
        if (targetVelocity != Vector3.zero)
        {
            animator.SetBool("isWalking", true);
        }
        else
        {
            animator.SetBool("isWalking", false);
        }

        if (isRunning)
        {
            animator.SetBool("isRunning", true);
            targetVelocity *= runningSpeed;
        }
        else
        {
            animator.SetBool("isRunning", false);
            targetVelocity *= speed;
        }

        targetVelocity = transform.TransformDirection(targetVelocity);
        Vector3 velocityChange = targetVelocity - currentVelocity;
        velocityChange = new Vector3(velocityChange.x, -1f, velocityChange.z);
        Vector3.ClampMagnitude(velocityChange, maxForce);
        rb.AddForce(velocityChange, ForceMode.VelocityChange);
    }
```

Comment: You can change the player rotation using transform.rotation: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-rotation.html